# $\int_0^\pi g(x)\sin(nx) dx$ coverges to $0$ for any function $g$ is bounded variation

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, bounded-variation

I have a homework as follows : Prove that $\int_0^\pi g(x)\sin(nx) dx$ coverges to $0$ for any function $g$ is bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

my attempt: for any bounded variation function $g$,

$$\int_0^\pi g(x)\sin(nx) dx =  -n \int_0^\pi g(x)d(\cos(nx))\\
= -\int_0^\pi \sin(nx)dg(x).$$

How to show $\int_0^\pi \sin(nx)dg(x)\to 0$?

Comment: take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: @Math-fun: I do not understand how to solve my problem using your hint.

Comment: note that $exp(inx)=\cos nx + i \sin nx$

Comment: $\int^\pi_0 \sin(nx)dg(x)\leq || sin(nx)||V(g:[0,\pi])$ where $||.||$ is sup-norm and $V(g,[a,b])$ is total variation of function $g$ on $[a,b]$. Then, $|| sin(nx)||\leq 1$. I don't know how to show $V(g:[0,\pi])\to 0$

Comment: You should have had $1/n$ on the right side of the first equality instead of $n$. That makes a big difference. And, the last term in the equality should have $\cos(nx)$ it in, not $\sin(nx)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\pi g(x)\sin(nx) dx =  -n \int_0^\pi g(x)d(\cos(nx))\\
= -\int_0^\pi \sin(nx)dg(x)\\= ||\frac{1}{n}\cos(nx)||_{\infty}V(g:[0,\pi]\\ =\frac{1}{n}||\cos(nx)||_{\infty}V(g:[0,\pi].$$

So, $\int_0^\pi g(x)\sin(nx) dx$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it correct?